# Is there a way to call a method from a separate class in a Java GUI?

Tags: java

I am working on a project for a class. The project asked me to create 3 classes, one parent and two children, with 3 methods in each. It then asked me to create a GUI that would calculate the sales tax based on a few fields, including text and radio buttons. In my head, I would call my methods to run if a certain radio button is clicked, ie if the Hybrid button is clicked, it'll run the toString from the Hybrid class. Can someone help me figure out how exactly to do this?

```
package projecttwo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import projectTwo.Automobile;
import projectTwo.Electric;
import projectTwo.Hybrid;

/**
 * CMIS242
 * November 14, 2020
 * Sabrina Riley
 * This program computes the sales tax for a collection of automobiles
 */
public class ProjectTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    //Variable declaration
    private String select;    
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label, label2, label3, label4, label5;
    private JFormattedTextField mmText, salesText, mpgText, weightText, compute;
    private JButton button, button2, button3;
    private JRadioButton hybrid, electric, other;
    private ButtonGroup bg;
    private JPanel radioPanel;
    Automobile car = new Automobile();
    
    public ProjectTwo() {
        //initialize GUI
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        //HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        //add compute sales tax button
        button = new JButton("Compute Sales Tax");
        button.setBounds(0,100,150,50);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        //add display results button
        button2 = new JButton("Display Results");
        button2.setBounds(0,200, 150, 50);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        
        //add clear fields button
        button3 = new JButton("Clear Fields");
        button3.setBounds(200,200, 150, 50);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        
         
        //add text field to display results from compute sales button
        compute = new JFormattedTextField();
        compute.setBounds(200,100,150,50);
        compute.setEditable(false);
        
        //add all other text fields
        mmText = new JFormattedTextField();
        mmText.addKeyListener(null);
        //mmText.addActionListener(this);
        salesText = new JFormattedTextField();
        mpgText = new JFormattedTextField();
        weightText = new JFormattedTextField();       
        
        //add radio buttons to pick between hybrid, electric, and other
        hybrid = new JRadioButton("Hybrid", true);        
        electric = new JRadioButton("Electric", false);        
        other = new JRadioButton("Other", false);
        
        //group the radio buttons together
        bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(hybrid);
        bg.add(electric);
        bg.add(other);
        
        //arrange buttons vertically
        radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        //radioPanel.setBounds(100,200,150,200);
        radioPanel.add(hybrid);
        radioPanel.add(electric);
        radioPanel.add(other);
        setContentPane(radioPanel);
        pack();
        
        
        //make them listen to clicks
        hybrid.addActionListener(this);
        electric.addActionListener(this);
        other.addActionListener(this);
        
        //label all text fields
        label = new JLabel("Make and Model");
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 150);
        label2 = new JLabel("Sales Price");
        label3 = new JLabel("Automobile Type");
        label4 = new JLabel("Miles Per Gallon");
        label5 = new JLabel("Weight in Pounds");
 
        //implement panel with all labels, text fields, buttons, and radio buttons
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        //panel.setLayout(GridLayout(0,2));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(mmText);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(salesText);
        panel.add(hybrid);
        panel.add(electric);
        panel.add(other);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(mpgText);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(weightText);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(compute);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);
        panel.add(radioPanel);

        //set frame dimensions
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Automobile Sales Tax Calculator");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String user = mmText.getText();
        String sales = salesText.getText();
        String mpg = mpgText.getText();
        String weight = weightText.getText();
        this.clearFields();
        e.getActionCommand();
        
        if(e.getSource()==hybrid) {
            System.out.println("car is a hybrid");
        } else if (e.getSource()==electric){
            System.out.println("car is electric");
        } else
            System.out.println("car is basic");
        
        System.out.println(", " + user + sales + ", " + weight + ", " + mpg);
        
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void clearFields() { 
        mmText.setText(null);
        salesText.setText(null);
        mpgText.setText(null);
        weightText.setText(null);
        compute.setText(null);
        hybrid.setSelected(false);
        electric.setSelected(false);
        other.setSelected(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new ProjectTwo();  
    }
}
```

```
package projectTwo;

/**
 * CMIS242
 * November 14, 2020
 * Sabrina Riley
 * This program computes the sales tax for a collection of automobiles
 */
public class Automobile {
    protected String make;
    protected String model;
    protected double salesPrice;
    protected double salesTax;
    
    public Automobile() {
        make = "brand";
        model = "type";
    }
    //A constructor that allows the make and purchase price to be initialized
    public Automobile(String make, String model, double salesPrice, double salesTax) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.salesPrice = salesPrice;
        this.salesTax = salesTax;
    }

    //A method that returns the base sales tax computed as 5% of the sales price
    public double salesTax() {
        salesTax = salesPrice * 0.05;
        return salesTax;
    }

    //A toString method that returns a string containing the make and model of the     
    //automobile, the sales price, and the sales tax
    public String toString() {
        return make + model + salesTax;
    }
}
```

```
package projectTwo;

/**
 * CMIS242
 * November 14, 2020
 * Sabrina Riley
 * This program computes the sales tax for a collection of automobiles
 */
public class Hybrid extends Automobile {
    protected int mpg;
    protected double discount;
    //A constructor that allows the make and purchase price to be initialized
    public Hybrid(int mpg) {
        super();
        
        mpg = 0;
    }
    
    public Hybrid(String make, String model, double salesPrice, double salesTax, int mpg) {
        super(make, model, salesPrice, salesTax);
        this.mpg = mpg; 
    }

    //A method that returns the base sales tax computed as 5% of the sales price
    @Override
    public double salesTax() {
        if (mpg  < 40) 
            discount = salesTax + 100;
        else 
            discount = salesTax + 100 + (mpg * 2);
        return discount;      
    }

    //A toString method that returns a string containing the make and model of the     
    //automobile, the sales price, and the sales tax
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return make + model + salesPrice + discount + discount;
    }    
}
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to call a method from a separate class in a Java GUI?"* Yes, there is, and it's Java 101 - something you should be familiar and comfortable with before ever attempting to make a GUI that needs to work across platforms. I suggest you put GUIs aside for the moment and work this out in two classes run form the command line or the IDE (without a GUI). Removing the [tag:swing] tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, if understand correctly what you want to achieve, you have to create an instance of the "Hybrid" class in ProjectTwo's constructor, just like:
Declare the variable there you have all variable declarations, just to have it global:

```
private Hybrid hybr;
```

Create the instance in constructor:

```
hybr = new Hybrid("make", "hybrid's model", 20500.50, 12.5, 5);
```

And then in your code, there where you need to use to Hybrid's methods you call you method, in this case `hybr.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you for your input! So I tried the following and now it won't compile. Any ideas?

       private Hybrid hCar;
        hCar = new Hybrid("make", "model", 0.00, 0.00, 0);

if(e.getSource()==hybrid) {
            System.out.println("car is a hybrid");
            hCar.toString();